# Something is about to happen

Tags: meaning

Something about to happen: If something is about to happen, it will happen very soon.

- https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/be-about-to

"My phones about to die. Luckily, I have a charger. I'll be right back."

Shouldn't we not use "about to" if we are going to not let it happen very soon? According to the definition, you use it when you think it will happen very soon. Can someone explain?

Comment: People don't usually speak with a flawless degree of precision. For example, we know you meant *phone's about to die*. You're asking if it's wrong because the charging will prevent it. No, it's still true in the moment.

Comment: In your example, *about to die* means *on the verge of dying* — not *going to die* in the sense of predestiny. The phone is on the verge of dying.